# Comparing dates using month and year only

Tags: compare

I'm trying to compare two dates consisting of the month and year only.  The month and year will be input by keyboard.  The result should be the age.

Any help will be appreciated...Thank you

Comment: Like everyone else says, we need the language.  If you happen to be using C#, see this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.month.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The logic behind this question is:

months = ( year 2 * 12 + months2 ) - ( year1 * 12 + months1 )
years = months / 12

Answer (score 0):

A generic answer would be to make the DAY constant at 1.

So in VBA it would look like:

```
IF SERIALDATE('1',monthVAR1,yearVAR1) = SERIALDATE('1',monthVAR2,yearVAR2) THEN
--DO STUFF
ELSE
--DO OTHER STUFF
END IF
```